# .net DateTime object, ensuring MM/DD/YYYY formatting

Tags: .net, sql, ms-access, datetime

It seems that the .net DateTime object defaults to whatever format the computer is set to. As I'm from the UK, this means that the DateTime object is DD/MM/YYYY.

This, typically, is fine, but I'm trying to use the DateTime object to put the current time in on a record submission on an Access database. Access (or SQL in general, don't really know) requires that the date is formatted in a MM/DD/YYYY format.

Is there a way I can have the DateTime object just format the date in the MM/DD/YYYY format, or am I going to have to convert to string, switch the string around, and insert that?

Comment: You probably should go with yyyy-MM-dd format (ISO 8601)

Comment: Actually, if you're using DateTime fields correctly, it won't matter what format the date is in, because there is no conversion to string.  You're not using concatenated sql strings, are you?  That would be bad.

Comment: Well, use parameterized queries and you won't have this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are inserting into a database don't use a Date String. Use a Parameter Object and give the Value the date object.

for access

```
string mystatment = "Insert into TableName (column1, datecolumn) values (?,?)"

OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.Commandtext = mystatement;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column1", mycolumn1variable);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datecolumn", yourDateTimeVariable);
```

if you are properly doing this with production code make sure you have exception handling etc.

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("connection string"))
{
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "Insert into TableName (column1, datecolumn) values (?,?)";

        OleDbParameter param;
        param = new OleDbParameter("name",  OleDbType.VarChar, 36); // if you know the size of the column specify it
        param.Value = mycolumn1variable;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

        param = new OleDbParameter("mydate", OleDbType.Date); // if you know the size of the column specify it
        param.Value = yourDateTimeVariable;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //etc
    }
}
```

for sql you use the named @parameters instead of the ? in your statement and use a SqlCommand instead.

If it's for screen display, repect the users settings and format based on their culture.

Comment: What's the reasoning behind this? The string concatenation I was doing ended up working fine, why would this method be superior?

Comment: as you've witnessed, the dates in string format are dependent upon location.. Think about 10 Januaary, and 1 October when you have US vs GB/AU date formats

Comment: Because with this method you're letting .NET and Access do the heavy lifting. Access can figure out the date, no matter what format. Let it. In theory, you database could be in a different context (and thus culture) than your program, so you don't want to tie that insertion down to a single culture. Plus hardcoding cultural formats is not good practice.

Comment: Ah right, thanks guys. I've modified my code to reflect this method, and I'll keep it in mind for the future.

Comment: @SamuelSmith - Another reason to not use concatenated strings is to protect from SQL Injection attacks.  Don't be fooled into thinking "My site won't be big enough for anyone to attack".  There are automated systems out there that scour the internet and attack any site they find (called worms), and then they turn your site into a host for viruses, malware, phishing, spam, and other nasties.  If you don't know what SQL Injection attacks are read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: DO use sql parameters (+1). Sql Injection is the main (though not the only) reason for this.  DO NOT use .AddWithValue(), as this relies on .Net to guess the sql datatype of the parameter object, and it doesn't always guess right. And sometimes when it guesses wrong, weird things and odd performance issues can crop up that can be hard to diagnose.

Comment: sorry I'll update that I was being lazy, I usually create the parameters fully in code

Answer (score 0):

You can call DateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") so you don't have to switch it around

Answer (score 0):

Use `ToString` method of `DateTime` structure:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

string s = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this when you utilize the `DateTime` class:

```
DateTime yourDate = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine("Your Date: {0}", yourDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I wasn't aware of the ToString overrides that DateTime had, thought I was going to have to convert it to a string and chop-n-change it, myself.

Comment: @SamuelSmith No need for the "chop-n-change".  The `DateTime` class is very easy work with and mold. :)  Glad I could help.